# ASP.NET mvc5 - @{ Html.BeginForm();} vs @using (Html.BeginForm())

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This might be a simple question for MVC experts, but I couldn't find an answer while googling.

I am reading a book about ASP.NET mvc, and the author said that it's recommended to use @using when creating forms as it will add the `</form>` at the end. However, when I tested the code without it with just `@{ Html.BeginForm();}`, it added the `</form>`. I understand the @using when being used with databases or objects that implement the IDisposable interface, but in this case, why is it even used for forms if it's doing the same as when it's not being used at all?

Code with @using:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </p>
        <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p>
        <p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p>
        <p>
            Will you attend?
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[] {
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I'll be there",
            Value = bool.TrueString},

            new SelectListItem() {Text = "No, I can't come",
            Value = bool.FalseString}
            }, "Choose an option")
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
    }
```

Code without @using:

```
 @{ Html.BeginForm(); }
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </p>
        <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p>
        <p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p>
        <p>
            Will you attend?
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[] {
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I'll be there",
            Value = bool.TrueString},

            new SelectListItem() {Text = "No, I can't come",
            Value = bool.FalseString}
            }, "Choose an option")
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
```

both will add the closing `</form>`
Thanks for any insights.

Comment: That code will not add `</form>`. If its being added, you have other code doing it (such as `@{ Html.EndForm; }`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see the updated question to see the code.